# Select option value - Obter do datatable

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-datatables

Gostaria que o select option pegasse os campos de uma coluna na tabela

**Meu select:**

```
<div class="dataTables_lenght">
             <label>
               <select id = "select1 " name="select1" aria-controls="example" >
                  <option value="">Existe</option>
                   <option value="">Não Existe</option>

              </select>
              Situação por página
            </label>            

           </div>
```

Meu script hoje.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {          
    "language": {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Portuguese-
           Brasil.json"
    }       
} );}); 
</script>
```

Meu code em php

```
foreach($ArrLog as $linhaDe){

                      for($x=0;$x<count($doc);$x++){
                        $condicaoSection = $doc->field[$x]["source"];
                        $linhaDe["status"] = "not found";
                        if ($condicaoSection == $linhaDe["de"]) {
                            $x = count($doc) + 1;
                            $linhaDe["status"] = "existe";


                        }

                    }
                              echo '<tr>
                              <td>'. $linhaDe["de"] . '</td>;
                              <td>'. $linhaDe["para"] . '</td><td>';

                if ($linhaDe["status"] == "existe"){
                            var_dump($linhaDe); 
                        echo '<span class="badge badge-success">Existe</span>';

                }   
                else
                        echo '<span class="badge badge-danger">Não Existe</span>';
                        echo '</td>

                          </tr>' ;  
                 }
```

Como faço pra pegar o valor da variável $linhaDe que este valor aparece na tabela  ,eu tbm colocar no select option e alterar na tabela... tipo um filtro  alguma dica??

Comment: Veja estes exemplos: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html, https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()

Comment: Não everson ..de javascript sou meio novo ainda as informações que são preenchidas neste datatable, ,são pega  através de um arquivo txt aew ele ler e colocar o conteúdo da tabela.. entendeu??

Comment: A caixa de pesquisar já não faz isso, quando você escreve alguma coisa? E por que duplicar o filtro de quantos registros serão exibidos por pagina? Não esta muito claro o que você quer.

Comment: editei a pergunta....

Comment: @RicardoMendes Você quer selecionar (usando o select 1) as linhas da tabela de acordo com o estado (existe ou não existe)? Ou você quer quer editar as linhas da tabela, mudando o texto existente?

Comment: @Juven_v sim, eu quero selecionar usando o select1 tipo se eu selecionar existe ,as linhas da tabela só me retorna os dados que existe, se selecionar Não existe retorna na tabela os dados que não existe.

Comment: A minha tabela tem as coluna DE - PARA   - e SITUACAO   meu datatable estar parecido com esse  (https://jsfiddle.net/c261r36x/)  a diferença é que os dados dentro da tabela são dados de um arquivo txt que separei e coloquei